# Select option value returns '[object Object]'

Tags: reactjs, formik

I would like to ask for your help. I have mapped a list of data `patientOptions` to select field, each option has a value of

```
  value: {
    id: patient.id,
    firstName: patient.firstName,
    middleName: patient.middleName,
    lastName: patient.lastName,
  },
```

I need to store this information when I submit the form. If I `console.log(patientOptions)` this will appear
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to get all values

```
  value: {
    id: 13412341234,
    firstName: John,
    middleName: Made,
    lastName: Doe,
  },
```

But if I will try to submit the form and log it to the console this will show up.

[image]

I have also tried just getting the value of 1 object it works but trying to get the value of multiple objects still returns the same error

Here is the rest of the code I hope anyone can help me.

```
const patientOptions = patient.map((patient) => ({
  key: `${patient.firstName} ${patient.middleName} ${patient.lastName},
  value: {
    id: patient.id,
    firstName: patient.firstName,
    middleName: patient.middleName,
    lastName: patient.lastName,
  },
}));

onSubmit = (values) =>
  console.log("form data", {
    patient: values.patient,
  });

<Formik
  initialValues={{
    patient: "",
  }}
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
>
  <Form>
    <FormikControl
      control="select"
      name="patient"
      label="Patient"
      options={patientOptions}
    />
  </Form>
</Formik>;
```

Comment: I gues value needs to be primitive `key: `${patient.firstName} ${patient.middleName} ${patient.lastName},
  value: patient.firstName`

Comment: This is a standard javascript feature, and from your report it works as intended. It is neither a diagnostic nor an error message. Perhaps you can elaborate on what you'd expect otherwise?

Comment: I noticed that in your onSubmit function call, you are not passing any arguments; maybe that's causing the problem. `onSubmit={()=>onSubmit(patientOptions )}` maybe you wanted to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: \[object Object\] passed through select/option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542236/react-object-object-passed-through-select-option-value)